# How to return the substring(s) from these indexes

Tags: ruby

To return the substring using an index, we can do this like so

```
string = "hello"
string[0] returns "h"
string[1] returns "e"
(and so on...)
```

Let's say I had an array [1,2,3,4] and a string "awesome". How would I return the relevant substring(s) from the array?

```
[1,2,3,4] should return "weso"
```

This is because I have a method which is meant to return the substring after every "r" and it is failing:

You can see that I have found the indexes for every substring "r" and  it is returned as an array. The line below  is incrementing each value in the array by +1.

I now need to return the substrings from the string by the relevant indexes from the array.

```
def pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr(string)

  all_index = (0 ... string.length).find_all {|i| string[i] ==  "r"}
  y = all_index.map do |i| i + 1
  end
  string[y.first..y.last]
end

# pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr("are you really learning Ruby?") # => "eenu"
# pirates_say_arrrrrrrrr("Katy Perry is on the radio!")   # => "rya"
```

Comment: "I have a method which is meant to return the substring after every 'r'" So what's the expected output for your example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,6]

"awesome".chars.values_at(*array).join
  #=> "wesoe"
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to make a major edit. didn't include my problem I am trying to solve which is relevant to the original question.

Comment: Please clarify the question (with an edit). I don't see how it has changed with your last edit. In your example you used offsets `[1,2,3,4]`. Readers may wonder if those indices are necessarily sequential. If not, it would be better to use something like `1,3,4,6`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland in this case, would `"awesome".chars[*array].join` also work ?

Comment: @UlysseBN, see [Array#\[\]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D). What happens for `['a','b','c','d'][0,2,3]`? Try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each_with_object(""){|i, s| s << "awesome"[i]}
# => "weso"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a contiguous substring don't forget you can slice a string:

```
> "awesome"[1..4]
=> "weso"
```

And to return the character after a match, don't forget you can use a regex:

```
> "Katy Perry is on the radio!".scan(/(?<=r)./)
=> ["r", "y", "a"]
```